# How to make a keyword for terminal

Tags: python, package, snapcraft

So basically, I have a python program (called: robot) that I want to run from anywhere (Any directory) in the terminal simply by typing its name and I want this to do the same thing that `python robot.py` would do.
How can I achieve this? Do I have to put robot on snap? If so, how can I do that. Please help, I am very new to this.
I am on linux (Ubuntu)

Comment: See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for guidelines on this forum. "How to" isn't really appropriate here. But to answer shortly: search for "entry points". You should find plenty of information.

Comment: This question is not concerning programming. The answer also depends heavily on the host operating system, which is not mentioned.

Comment: That's more a linux problem. Add a shebang to the script, make it executable with chmod and put it in a directory which is covered by the path variable or make a softlink. If you need more information about this, there are enough keywords in this comment to search for.

Comment: Could you please share a link regarding this because I am really struggling @Wups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this is a UNIX based terminal, you can add an alias on your bash profile. Not too related to python itself.

Edit your ".bash_aliases" file under your home directory.
Add the following line

```
alias robo='python /path/to/file/robot.py'
```

Then restart your terminal session or run:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
```

Now typing "robo" on terminal should run the python file.
This does not source any virtual environments you use.

--

Another method is to create a bash script to run this, then you can add the script to path.

Comment: Hi, I couldn't find .bash_profile. I am on ubuntu. I did however find: .bashrc , .bash_logout and bash_history.  Is it any of these? @adam

Comment: Also, @adam, I put it in the .bashrc file but now when typing robot in terminal it is showing this: can't find '____main____' module

Comment: Does my python script need '____main____' module? What is that?

Comment: what exactly did you put on the .bashrc file and where? I'd say it's generally a good idea to leave the file alone, but it's no issue.

Comment: I got my mistake, I mistyped a letter. Thanks a lot!